# Extracting Data Related to a Value, but Excluding the Value Itself

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have a date table Employees, and I want to write a query that will prompt the user an employee last name. The query then displays the last name and hire date of any employee in the same department as the employee whose name the user supply (excluding that employee). For example, if I enter Smith, the query will find all employees who work with Smith, but excluding Smith himself.

The code I wrote so far is:

```
    select e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id, e.hire_date 
    from employees e
    where e.department_id = (select department_id
                             from employees
                             where last_name = initcap('&l_name'))
    and e.last_name <> initcap('&l_name');
```

However, this code does not prompt me for any last name when I run it, and it automatically displays a single last name, employee ID, department ID, and hire date. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after going over it a few more times, I solved it:

```
 select e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id
 from employees e
 where e.department_id = (select department_id 
                           from employees 
                           where last_name = initcap('&l_name'))
 and e.last_name <> initcap('&l_name');
```

Also, it turns out I didn't need to show the hire date.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle You could use minus  (for subtract the result set of the second select from the first result set)

```
    select e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id, e.hire_date 
    from employees e
    where e.department_id = (select department_id
                             from employees
                             where last_name = initcap('&l_name'))
    minus 
    select e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id, e.hire_date 
    from employees 
    where last_name = initcap('&l_name')
```

Comment: your code does the same thing; it simply returns an employee name, his employee ID, department ID, and hire date. It doesn't prompt the user for any input.

Comment: This mean that your subselect don't select the any department_id  ... you should check this ..